# How to make Google Assistant reply

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I got the Google Assistant running on a Raspberry. Everything is working fine but there is one thing that I cannot figure out.

I know that ifttt.com has the ability to make the Google Assistant reply with spoken language using text that you can predefine.

How can I do that using Python? I cannot find anything about that subject on the      Google Assistant SDK page. How can I make the Google Assistant talk back? Is there documentation about this subject?

Example:

If I tell the Assistant:

"Light's out."

I want it to reply:

"Yes sir, the lights are out."

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: I don't know if this is a standard comment (as this is my first post) but I don't have code on this subject, because I don't even know where to start. I cannot find it in the documentation for the python library.

Comment: "I don't know where to start" doesn't tend to work very well on Stack Overflow.  If you can demonstrate that you've already done some research and the available resources don't answer your question, then you're more likely to attract good answers.  As it stands, the question is so broad it's hard to know where to begin.

Comment: I will try to adapt my question based on your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

By hosting your backend fulfillment from your Raspberry Pi you can build an action in Google Assistant which can control both your GPIO pins and can send out custom replies as you wanted above. I used flask and ngrok to host from my Raspberry Pi and create a webhook.